# Angular Material Tooltip

Tags: angular-material

I have a problem when I was using Angular Material to build my project. I want to show the operation history of the user with tooltip.Each line a piece of data.Just like this,
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSDRc.png)
.The code is as following:

```html
<md-button class="md-icon-button" data-ng-mouseover="operation_history($event, u.uid)">
                <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom" style="width: 250px;">
                <div data-ng-show="operation_historys">
                <div data-ng-repeat="operation_history in operation_historys">
          <span>{{operation_history.create_name}}： {{operation_history.create_time}}&nbsp;
          {{operation_history.old_status}} -&gt;{{operation_history.new_status}}</span><br>
             </div>
             </div>
                </md-tooltip>
                <i class="material-icons md-18">history</i>
            </md-button>
```

Now the problem is, the tooltip only show the first line data. But I can see the Dom structure of the rest datas in Chrome.I do not know where the problem is.Please help me. It is my first time to ask a questions here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems md-tooltip height is set equal to line height in angular material.

Try the following.

```
.md-content.md-show{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Check this pen for demo [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbzYRX?editors=1100).